# How to apply jquery javascript to multiple <a> tags

Tags: jquery, pdf, iframe, dialog

I have this  tag:
`<a id="link1"  runat="server" href="http://www.selab.isti.cnr.it/ws-mate/example.pdf" title="PDF">Open iFrame</a>`


This link opens a jquery ui dialog that contains an iframe of a PDF file with this javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
    $("#<%=link1.ClientID%>").click(function() {
        //e.preventDefault();
        var $this = $(this);
        $('<iframe id="externalSite"  frameborder="0" src="' + this.href + '" />').dialog({
            title: ($this.attr('title')) ? $this.attr('title') : 'External Site',
            autoOpen: true,
            width: 700,
            height: 600,
            modal: true,
            resizable: true,
            overlay: {
                opacity: 0.5,
                background: "black"
            }
        }).width(650).height(550);
        return false;
    });
});
</script>
```

But i need to apply this block of code to mulitple a tags (the number of links can go up to dozens). I know how to create these links in my code behind using a loop, but I dont know how to get every link to work dynamically with the PDF its asigned to open.
help?

Comment: These answers all require markup changes, if you don't want to change your markup, use my code. `$('a[id^=link]')` will match all "A" elements that begin with the word "link" and apply the click function. So if you have `link1` - `link87`, all links from 1 through 87 will have a click function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a class to the `<a>` tag while rendering from the server like `class="iframelink"`

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
    $(".iframelink").click(function() {
        //e.preventDefault();
        var $this = $(this);
        $('<iframe id="externalSite"  frameborder="0" src="' + this.href + '" />').dialog({
            title: ($this.attr('title')) ? $this.attr('title') : 'External Site',
            autoOpen: true,
            width: 700,
            height: 600,
            modal: true,
            resizable: true,
            overlay: {
                opacity: 0.5,
                background: "black"
            }
        }).width(650).height(550);
        return false;
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: got a second question. how do i add an <asp:button> to this jquery dialog?

Comment: I am not sure if you can add a `<asp:button>` as it is a server side tag. But where do you want to add it?

Comment: How does it render, but yea, you can add. What happens if you add it in the code in teh server side? Does it display in the browser? How is the HTML formed?

Comment: There is no html, only a button with javascript. So i cant access this dialog from the code behind

Answer (score 1):

Use a class on the link and apply the code to the class name:

```
<a id="link1" class="changethis" runat="server" href="http://www.selab.isti.cnr.it/ws-mate/example.pdf" title="PDF">Open iFrame</a>
```

Then change your javascript to:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
    $(".changethis").click(function() { // Use the CLASS here, not the ID
        //e.preventDefault();
        var $this = $(this);
        $('<iframe id="externalSite"  frameborder="0" src="' + this.href + '" />').dialog({
            title: ($this.attr('title')) ? $this.attr('title') : 'External Site',
            autoOpen: true,
            width: 700,
            height: 600,
            modal: true,
            resizable: true,
            overlay: {
            opacity: 0.5,
            background: "black"
        }
    }).width(650).height(550);
    return false;
});
});
</script>
```

You can have an unlimited number of hyperlinks with that same class name, and the function will execute each time any link with that class is clicked.

Comment: got a second question. how do i add an <asp:button> to this jquery dialog?

Answer (score 0):

Give all the anchor tags the same class, then select them by class.

```
<a class="thelink" runat="server" href="http://www.selab.isti.cnr.it/ws-mate/example.pdf" title="PDF">Open iFrame</a>
```

and js:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
    $(".thelink").click(function() {
        //e.preventDefault();
        var $this = $(this);
        $('<iframe id="externalSite"  frameborder="0" src="' + this.href + '" />').dialog({
            title: ($this.attr('title')) ? $this.attr('title') : 'External Site',
            autoOpen: true,
            width: 700,
            height: 600,
            modal: true,
            resizable: true,
            overlay: {
                opacity: 0.5,
                background: "black"
            }
        }).width(650).height(550);
        return false;
    });
});
</script>
```

That one block of js will affect all anchor tags with the `thelink` class.

Answer (score 0):

As stated in other answers, adding a class to your links would be a good solution. But, if you didn't want to or couldn't, you can use an 'ends with' selector to grab only your PDf links.

```
// use the 'ends with' selector on the href attribute
$('a[href$=pdf]').click(function() {
    // do your stuff here, using $(this) to reference the clicked link attributes
    alert($(this).attr('id'));
    return false;
});​
```

I posted a [jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/joemaller/fqTnz/) showing how it this works.